# Recognize handwritten equations - OCR

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am writing an app that recognizes handwritten equations on photos, I need a model that, with this photo as input:

[image]

Would return the following string: `9 - 3 / 1 / 3 + 1 =`.

I already have a TensorFlow model, that can recognize digits, but it was trained with the "mnist" dataset, which means it won't be able to work with "real world data". My question is: where can I find good data sets to train my model and what are the alternatives to TensorFlow I could use to create it?

P.S I don't need my model to recognize complex symbols like the integral one. 
Only simple symbols like `+, -, =, /, *` and the sqrt one

Answer (score 1):

How about writing a program to generate random equations and creating an image out of it by replacing the digits with images from the MNIST data-set. Here is your equation with the digits replaced with images from the MNIST data-set, for better clarification:
[image]

Comment: Yes, but  how will my main model know how to convert 3 % 1 (fraction bar) 3 to 3 / 1 / 3